# Handling "Internal server error" in Groovy-Console

Tags: exception, groovy, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a groovy-script which takes about 5 hours to complete (it restarts (delete old and start new) many workflows), and unfortunately there are some workflows which can't get processed and throw an "internal Server error" which ends the groovy call.

**All I can do now is to take a look at the logs and restart the groovy script and exclude the problematic workflow-id.**

It would be a great performance-boost, **if I could catch this "internal server error"**  in the hac and continue with the next workflow **instead of aborting the skript**.

I already tried to put it in try/catch, but this doesn't work.

Is there any chance to "ignore" the "internal server error"s - entries of my list to process?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: use a try/catch block or a HTTP library that can trap HTTP 500 responses? Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Groovy script natively, not through the HAC. The Groovy/Beanshell consoles are handy for quick prototypes, but running a 5-hr process through a browser interface seems kludgy at best. You have at least a couple options:

## Dynamic Beans

Did you know that Spring beans can be implemented using a number of various languages using [Dynamic language beans](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+language+beans+in+Spring)?

Define interfaces for your processes and wire them up to Groovy implementations using the Spring configuration. Since the scripts are interpreted at runtime, you can swap out code without needing to recompile the entire platform.

Now you have the full power of Java, Spring, Groovy, and hybris. Properly sequester each process so that exceptions don't bubble up and crash the entire thing.

This option would be the cleanest way to go, since you'd be integrating the code directly into the project's codebase. And you can keep all your existing [ Groovy | JRuby | Beanshell | ... ] code.

## Roll your own

Another thing you might try is examining hybris' Groovy API. I was able to leverage hybris' Beanshell interpreter classes to create my own test harness. It is a simple standalone Eclipse project that allows me to write and run Beanshell within Eclipse, with output to the console. I use it on a daily basis for quick scripting tasks like batch updates, FlexibleSearch queries, etc. I'd imagine you could do the same thing with Groovy. Search the hybris API for the HAC code that interprets the Groovy requests from the browser.

---

The sky's the limit, but first get out of the browser console for heavy scripting tasks.

Comment: Many thanks for your hint; The thing is that these groovy-scripts are written parallel to the business working with the live system. to there are no "standard" scripts which are startet every week for example. Is it possible to integrate such individual scripts (not known for the moment, but later) in hybris (i just switch the code of a class?) without building and restarting the whole thing?

Comment: an example for one of these 5hour scripts are: "restart all workflows which are in a definied condition"

Comment: Niko, It's definitely possible to swap out code with [Spring Dynamic Beans](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+language+beans+in+Spring). Do you know where the exception is being mishandled, by starting a remote debug session? I would think you could simply wrap your method calls in `try` blocks. Handle the `Exception`s appropriately all within the Groovy script and all within the browser console. Although I still think it's fairly trivial to create a "console" in Eclipse or your IDE of choice. It can be completely separate, "parallel" to the live system as you said.

Answer (score 0):

My short answer would be: **Don't use scripts for time-consuming processes.**

Although you mentioned that is not possible to define ***standard scripts***, because Business is working in parallel, I cannot recommend maintaining a live system in this manner.

Integrate that logic into a ***custom CronJob*** and add all configurable/dynamic things as properties of said Job.

The benefit of this approach would be

- you have a proper logging mechanism (Sysout in HAC Groovy console sux)
- you can trace your execution (time consumed, started, stopped, etc.)
- can be triggered automatically (CronJob Trigger) or by other instructed user (eg Operations)
- you get a more stable workflow as a whole (that is, no need of keeping track of those magic scripts (how do you version them? in the resource folder?))

The downside of this would be indeed, that **you need a redeploy**.

From my experience, dynamically changed code (Dynamic Beans as an example) works on projects with comparably low complexity, but tends to get messy pretty quickly.